# Best self defence Martial Art for small woman?

Tags: judo, self-defense, gender, multiple-attackers

I am a highschool girl, and I need to learn how to defend myself. I’ve looked into Muay Thai but I want to find something fit for me: I’m small - skinny and short. I am very agile but I lack strength.

I want to be able to defend myself and put my (larger male) opponents on the ground (or at least so that they will stop harassing and hurting me...).

What is the best martial art for self defence for a smaller woman?

Comment: We also have guidelines for how to ask about [martial arts recommendations](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). There is also the [tour](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tour).